# Data replication stalled and failed to start data transfer in AWS Application Migration Service

Tags: amazon-web-services

[Stalled data replication on AWS MGN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFgrH.jpg)

I need help resolving this stalled server migration from Oracle Linux 8.4 server to AWS EC2 using Application migration service.

The first time I tried to migrate the server, the process was successful but the instance failed system status check on EC2 dashboard on the console. After disconnecting the server and reinstalling the replication agent installer the data replication had been stalling.

I need assistance on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I am kind of stuck with a similar case, could you please update here if you were able to resolve this and if yes how? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This will be related to network communications not being correctly configured. Review this [section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mgn/latest/ug/preparing-environments.html) in detail and confirm all prerequisites have been met.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34469338)